# efficiently add rows if discontinuity : cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data. I need help here because If you see the timestamp there is discontinuity and I want to fill it with previous row.

The whole dataset is at 30 min interval, So If you look at the row 3 and 4 there is discontinuity, as you see there is an increase in one hour and then in next row 2 hours. So I want to fill here the missing rows with previous row values by just changing the current timestamp to timestamp+30.

Input Data:

| Timestamp | eqmt_id | brand_brew_code | level | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28-03-2021 09:00 | 1 | AB | 12.99 | 1 |
| 28-03-2021 09:30 | 2 | BB | 123.43 | 2 |
| 28-03-2021 10:00 | 1 | AB | 13.34 | 3 |
| 28-03-2021 11:00 | 1 | AB | 213.34 | 1 |
| 28-03-2021 14:00 | 1 | AB | 12. 322 | 1 |

Expected Outcome:

| Timestamp | eqmt_id | brand_brew_code | level | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28-03-2021 09:00 | 1 | AB | 12.99 | 1 |
| 28-03-2021 09:30 | 2 | BB | 123.43 | 2 |
| 28-03-2021 10:00 | 1 | AB | 13.34 | 3 |
| 28-03-2021 10:30 | 1 | AB | 13.34 | 3 |
| 28-03-2021 11:00 | 1 | AB | 213.34 | 1 |
| 28-03-2021 11:30 | 1 | AB | 213.34 | 1 |
| 28-03-2021 12:00 | 1 | AB | 213.34 | 1 |
| 28-03-2021 12:30 | 1 | AB | 213.34 | 1 |
| 28-03-2021 13:00 | 1 | AB | 213.34 | 1 |
| 28-03-2021 13:30 | 1 | AB | 213.34 | 1 |
| 28-03-2021 14:00 | 1 | AB | 12. 322 | 1 |

I have tried this code but outcome is also matching, but getting stopped in between. Don't know the issue.

```
#dfz is master df

appended_data = []
for i in df.eqmt_id:
  for j in df.brand_brew_no:
    df  = dfz[(dfz['eqmt_id'] == i) & (dfz['brand_brew_no'] == j)]

    df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']), inplace=True)
    df2 = df.reindex(
        pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='30min')
    ).fillna(method='ffill')
   
    temp = df2.reset_index()
    appended_data.append(temp)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-a1a0fbad32b2> in <module>
      4 
      5         df2.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestamp']), inplace=True)
----> 6         df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.reindex(pd.date_range(df2.Timestamp.min(), df2.Timestamp.max(), freq='30min')).fillna(method='ffill'))
      7         temp = df2.reset_index()
    


Error : ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Its coming because looks like in the main data, there can we a rows where previous timestamp and next timestamp is same. So please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

1. Convert `Timestamp` to `datetime`.
2. Set `Timestamp` as `index`.
3. Use `asfreq('30T')` to fill the `missing time`. `ffill` the missing value with `downcast = 'infer'` to retain the `dtype`.
4. Use `reset_index()` to get the same structure.

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
df = df.asfreq('30T').ffill(downcast='infer').reset_index()
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
             Timestamp  eqmt_id brand_brew_code    level  volume
0  2021-03-28 09:00:00        1              AB   12.990       1
1  2021-03-28 09:30:00        2              BB  123.430       2
2  2021-03-28 10:00:00        1              AB   13.340       3
3  2021-03-28 10:30:00        1              AB   13.340       3
4  2021-03-28 11:00:00        1              AB  213.340       1
5  2021-03-28 11:30:00        1              AB  213.340       1
6  2021-03-28 12:00:00        1              AB  213.340       1
7  2021-03-28 12:30:00        1              AB  213.340       1
8  2021-03-28 13:00:00        1              AB  213.340       1
9  2021-03-28 13:30:00        1              AB  213.340       1
10 2021-03-28 14:00:00        1              AB   12.322       1
```

###### Complete working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Timestamp': {0: '28-03-2021 09:00',
                   1: '28-03-2021 09:30',
                   2: '28-03-2021 10:00',
                   3: '28-03-2021 11:00',
                   4: '28-03-2021 14:00'},
     'eqmt_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
     'brand_brew_code': {0: 'AB', 1: 'BB', 2: 'AB', 3: 'AB', 4: 'AB'},
     'level': {0: 12.99, 1: 123.43, 2: 13.34, 3: 213.34, 4: 12.322},
     'volume': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1}}
)

df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
df = df.asfreq('30T').ffill(downcast='infer').reset_index()
```

*NOTE*: Here's one way to deal with duplicate timestamp ->

```
df = df.sort_values('Timestamp').drop_duplicates('Timestamp' , keep = 'last')
```

Comment: I am still getting : ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: I am still getting : ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis @Nk03

Comment: @simpleboi I've added the complete working example. You probably have duplicate timestamp entries. You need to check how to deal with duplicates. Will add one option.

Comment: @simpleboi I've updated my answer. currently, I'm keeping the last row in case of a duplicate timestamp entry you can modify the keep parameter as per your requirement